# Silverlight; Remove a child element from a parent

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, devexpress, tabcontrol

I'm trying to remove a child element but I am not sure how to do it...

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <Grid x:Name="ChildPanel">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="StackPanelImplementationSteps">
           <sdk:ValidationSummary x:Name="ValidationSummary"/>
           <dx:DXTabControl x:Name="DXTabControl_ViewTypes">
               <dx:DXTabControl.View>
                   <dx:TabControlScrollView HeaderLocation="Left" HeaderOrientation="Vertical"></dx:TabControlScrollView>
               </dx:DXTabControl.View>
               <dx:DXTabItem x:Name="tabImplementationSteps" Cursor="Hand" Header="Implementation Steps">
                   <Grid x:Name="ImpPanel">
                   </Grid>
              </dx:DXTabItem>
            <dx:DXTabControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Any idea how I can remove the ImpPanel from its parent 'tabImplementationSteps'??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[DXTabItem](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/clsDevExpressXpfCoreDXTabItemtopic) content is available via the DXTabItem.Content property. Thus you can use this property to add or remove remove the content at any time.

Tab items can be hidden/shown from UI using the DXTabControl embedded feature: [Showing and Hiding Tab Items](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument5002).
Tab items can be removed in code via the [DXTabControl.RemoveTabItem](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/DevExpressXpfCoreDXTabControl_RemoveTabItemtopic) method.

Related help article: [DXTabControl Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument5001)